# convert an image into an Fourier image in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, image, fft

First time here, and was hoping that someone would be able to help with an issue I’ve been dealing with. I performed the 2D fast Fourier transform on an image data, but got an error of the line norm_fourier_img all time, I want to know how I can correctly write that line and be able to obtain the Fourier image?

```
from PIL import Image
from array import array
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from numpy.linalg import norm, det

#load the image data into a numpy array
img = Image.open("1-z2-ex1250-p20-ch1hv100t0001.tif")
img_data = np.asarray(img)

#perform the 2D fast Fourier transform on the image data and...
fourier = np.fft.fft2(img_data)
fourier = np.fft.fftshift(fourier)
fourier = abs(fourier)
fourier = np.log10(fourier)

#calculate the original contrast range
lowest = np.nanmin(fourier[np.isfinite(fourier)])
highest = np.nanmax(fourier[np.isfinite(fourier)])
original_range = highest - lowest

#convert the normalized data into an image
norm_fourier = (highest - lowest) / original_range * 255
norm_fourier_img = Image.fromarray(norm_fourier)

#display the original image and the Fourier image
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax1.imshow(img, cmap = "gray")
ax2.imshow(norm_fourier_img)
ax1.title.set_text("Original Image")
ax2.title.set_text("Fourier Image")
plt.show()

#show the normalized Fourier image
norm_fourier_img.show()

#convert the output image to 8-bit pixels (grayscale) and save it
norm_fourier_img.convert("L").save("test.bnp")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmDOv.jpg) errors information

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLaUd.jpg)
this is the original image needed to be converted to Fourier image, but can't see anything come up in the Fourier side.

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     26 norm_fourier = (highest - lowest) / original_range * 255
     27 ##convert the normalized data into an image
---> 28 norm_fourier_img = Image.fromarray(norm_fourier)
     29 
     30 # display the original image and the Fourier image

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2441         raise ValueError("Too many dimensions: %d > %d." % (ndim, ndmax))
   2442 
-> 2443     size = shape[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmDOv.jpg), shape[0]
   2444     if strides is not None:
   2445         if hasattr(obj, 'tobytes'):

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can improve your question by adding the error as text instead of providing an image.

Comment: with thanks adding the error as text:

Comment: It looks like `norm_fourier` is a scalar, not a numpy array. Hence, `norm_fourier_img = Image.fromarray(norm_fourier)` fails, because `fromarray()` expects an array.  Could you try `norm_fourier = (1.0 / original_range) * 255*(fourier-lowest)` ?